# ASP/VB Classic clear a line from a file

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Alpha,25,SomeBrand,Info
Gamma,2039,Crisps,Foobar
Epic,240,Win,Post
```

And I want to clear a certain line in this file, say line 2, so that it looks like this:

```
Alpha,25,SomeBrand,Info

Epic,240,Win,Post
```

How can I efficiently do this? This file has over 18000 lines, and I've tried reading in the complete file and writing back, but it was way too slow.

Comment: What are your criteria for lines to clear?

Comment: @Jennifer S: Nothing other than a line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your file size but i've written a script (asp) is executed within 2.5 seconds.
Text file size is 35 million bytes and it has 35,000 lines.

Here:

```
<%@Language = VBScript %>
<%
Option Explicit

Dim oFso, oFile, arrLns, arrLNums, strOut, e
arrLNums = Array(15) '15th [and nnth] line(s) will be cleared

Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = oFso.OpenTextFile("C:\old.txt", 1)

    strOut = Replace(oFile.ReadAll(), vbCr, "")
    arrLns = Split(strOut, vbLf)
    For Each e In arrLNums : arrLns(e - 1) = "" : Next
    strOut = Join(arrLns, vbCrLf)
    oFso.CreateTextFile("C:\cleared.txt", True)_
    .Write(strOut) 'Saved

oFile.Close
Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFso = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use file pointer moving tricks to change the file 'on disk' in VBScript, you'll have to re-write it. Did you test whether using .ReadAll() and .Write is 'fast enough' for you? If yes, we could discuss a way to do the modifying efficiently. First question: Do you want to delete the offending line, or should it be replaced with an empty one?

Next Step:

This VBScript code:

```
  Dim goFS      : Set goFS     = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

  Dim sDir      : sDir         = "..\testdata\editlargefile"
  Dim sSrcFSpec : sSrcFSpec    = goFS.BuildPath( sDir, "lines.txt" )
  Dim nLine     : nLine        = 5
  Dim nSize     : nSize        = goFS.GetFile( sSrcFSpec ).Size
  WScript.Echo nSize, "bytes in", sSrcFSpec

  ReDim aHead( nLine - 2 )
  Dim oTS, nIdx, sTail

  Set oTS = goFS.OpenTextFile( sSrcFSpec )
  For nidx = 0 To UBound( aHead )
      aHead( nIdx ) = oTS.ReadLine()
  Next
  oTS.ReadLine
  sTail = oTS.ReadAll()
  oTS.Close

  WScript.Echo Left( Join( aHead, vbCrLf ) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Left( sTail, 100 ), 150 )

  Set oTS = goFS.CreateTextFile( sSrcFSpec, True )
  oTS.Write Join( aHead, vbCrLf )
  oTS.Write vbCrLf & vbCrLf
  oTS.Write sTail
  oTS.Close
```

output:

```
20888896 bytes in ..\testdata\editlargefile\lines.txt
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4

This is line 6
This is line 7
This is line 8
This is line 9
This is line 10
Thi
=====================================================
xplfs.vbs: Erfolgreich beendet. (0) [11.42188 secs]
```

demonstrates the fastest VBScript way I can think of. The pseudo code
for a language able to do file pointer tricks would be

```
Open the file in read+write mode
Loop over the head lines to keep
If Delete
   Skip line to delete
   Reset write file pointer to end of previous line
   Block write to file pointer till end
Else
   Fill line to delete with spaces
End
Close the file
```

What language do you plan to use?

Comment: It must be replaced with an empty one, even all-spaces if necessary for "file pointer tricks".

Comment: As I said: you can't do file-pointer tricks in VBScript. Did you test if .ReadAll() + .Write is 'fast enough'? If not, did you consider using another language (C++, C#, Perl, ...) for this (sub)task?

Comment: Yes I did, and I'll have to consider another language then because ReadAll and Write aren't fast enough (10 seconds).

Comment: Ekkehard.Horner: No ASP solution was fast enough for me so I wrote up something in C++. Blazing fast.